# Using Mercurial via pip on Ubuntu 20.04, any negative side-effects I should be expecting?

Tags: package-management, python3, equivs

I'm trying to get rid of the last Python 2.x bits on my Ubuntu 20.04 boxes and it turns out the `mercurial` package is the culprit.

Having already had some negative experiences with the packaged version of Mercurial in the past, I though I could simply install `python3-pip` and then do the `sudo python3 -m pip install mercurial` routine.

The binary ends up in `/usr/local/bin/hg` instead of `/usr/bin/hg`, but I guess it's okay for most purposes.

Questions:

1. should I have to expect any negative side-effects as long as I stay clear of packaged `mercurial` and friends (i.e. packages directly related to it)?

   - As an extension of this, should I use `equivs-build` (package `equivs`) to build myself a dummy that will artificially conflict with `mercurial`?
2. can I use `dpkg-divert` at all to symlink the `hg` binary into the well-known path (`/usr/bin/hg`)? Or will this only actually work if my dummy package takes care of it? Since I am using `hg` via SSH I am afraid that there is a chance the `hg` binary won't be found (Mercurial works by establishing an SSH tunnel and invoking `hg` to communicate via `std{in,err,out}` with the client) ...

Comment: Did you tried [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1229850/66509)? It is 100% python3.

Comment: No, I haven't. But for starters _any_ package installed without making the package source known to `apt` is a sore spot (subverts my aim to use Ansible for as many aspects of system configuration as possible). And making _this_ package source known to Ubuntu 20.04, while possible (pinning and all), is anything but desirable. Since I am also maintaining a Mercurial extension, I can live with having Mercurial installed "outside of the package manager". But installing a package from Debian experimental and doing it from this source seems a bit too risky for my taste. But thanks for the pointer.